# css3 transform visibility issue

Tags: css, transform, css-transforms

I need to fix landscape orientation for mobile website, so I'm using `@media (orientation: portrait) {}`. But I have one issue that I can't find solution: after using body transform - children items displaying outside box. Below there is a full example. You can save it and run in FF or chrome with mobile emulation (right-click at page, then "inspect element", then change emulation type).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sample</title>
<style>
    * {margin: 0; paddin: 0}
    html {position: relative; height: 100%}
    body {background: #ccc; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; padding-bottom: 30px}
    .box {background: #777; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%}

    @media (orientation: portrait) {
        body {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform-origin: left top;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, idea is to display `.box` in portrait mode like it comes in landscape - overlay on lightgray body with right padding. Here is image example how it must be: http://screencloud.net/v/EOXO

Comment: Media queries only style the content when their conditions are met, they don't force a layout. So if the width of the page is more than the height, the `orientation:portrait` CSS will be applied.

Comment: I know this and my question is about another trouble. When I'm using `rotate (90)` content box is moving away from visible area, so I'm asking about how to force it to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this question. But I found solution and maybe it could be helpful for someone. Here is a working code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sample</title>
<style>
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0}
    body {background: #ccc; position: relative; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; padding-bottom: 30px}
    .box {background: #c00; position: relative; max-width: 100%; height: 100%}

    @media (orientation: portrait) {
        body {
            transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
            transform-origin: left top;
            width: 100vh;
            height: 100vw;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So. First of all, I've changed dimensions to viewport relative values (100vh = 100% from viewport height and 100vw = 100% from viewport width).

Then, when I'm using a transformation into portrait orientation, I forgot about that width must become height and height = width.

Also, if I'm using a transform-origin property, it rotates as it sould - based on left top corner. So, it must be negative translated to be visible.

Hope this solution will be helpful for someone.